# Minibuffer prompt not displaying (intermittently) in daemon mode

Tags: minibuffer, daemon

I am using Emacs 24.5 on Mac OS (installed with homebrew) in daemon mode. I normally leave the daemon running for long periods of time (weeks) while I'm working. I'll open up files from the command line using `emacsclient -n`.

I've noticed is that emacsclient will block if opening the file causes a minibuffer prompt. For instance, if I've already got the file open and the file on disk differs from the file in the associated buffer. 99% of the time, I just switch to emacs, answer yes (or sometimes no) and everything works perfectly.

However, intermittently, emacsclient will block, as will the emacs GUI, but no minibuffer message will be displayed. My only option at this point seems to be killing the daemon. It's almost as if the minibuffer message is being displayed on a non-existent frame (I often work with multiple frames).

Two questions:

1. Does anyone know what's going on here - and perhaps a way to prevent it?
2. Is there a way to unblock a blocked emacs daemon? C-g from the GUI isn't having any effect.

Comment: If the minibuffer is waiting for your input in one frame, and in another frame, you're calling `M-x somecommand`, there will be a freeze, as, Emacs is still waiting for your input in the precedent frame. Maybe I'm wrong, but it seems what's you're experiencing :\

Comment: @Nsukami_ - I agree. The problem is that no frame (that I can see) is prompting.

Comment: If by some mean, the frame containing the minibuffer waiting for the input was closed, well, emacs is still waiting for that input, and all the other frames will be frozen, and you won't be able to see that emacs is waiting for an input :\

Comment: @Nsukami_ - I'm not intentionally (or accidentally, that I know of) closing that frame, but this is exactly what I think is happening. Do you know of any way to break out of this state without killing emacs?

Comment: Without killing emacs, I don't know :(